# Swift : How to refactor my code using more elegant approach?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, functional-programming

I wrote a piece of code that creates an array of objects based on the array of dictionaries. The problem is my solution, it's written in very noob way using multiple loops imperatively.

Let's consider the following case. There is a class called "Drug"

```
class Drug {

var name:String
var dosage:[(dose:String,time:String)]

init(name:String){

    self.name = name
    self.dosage = []
    }
}
```

I obtain the data as an array of dictionaries, here is the example:

```
var array = [["drugName":"Amotaks", "time":"17.00", "dose":"5"], ["drugName":"Amotaks", "time":"18.00", "dose":"5"], ["drugName":"Amotaks", "time":"18.00", "dose":"5"], ["drugName":"Amotaks", "time":"17.00", "dose":"5"], ["drugName":"Claritin", "time":"17.00", "dose":"5"], ["drugName":"Claritin", "time":"18.00", "dose":"5"]]
```

Now is the tricky part, what is the best way to turn this data into an array of Drug objects? I am not glad of my solution because it uses nested loops, additional helper arrays thus it's very inefficient.
The purpose is to create objects without repeating their names and provide each object with an dosage array which consist of (dose, time) tuples)

```
var DrugArray:[Drug] = []
    var drugs:[String] = []

    for i in array

        {
        if contains(drugs, i["drugName"]! as String){
            continue
            }
        else{

            drugs.append(i["drugName"]!)
            DrugArray.append(Drug(name: i["drugName"]!))

            }

        }

    for a in DrugArray{

        for i in array {
            if i["drugName"]! == a.name
            {
                a.dosage.append(dose: i["dose"]!, time: i["time"]!)

            }

        }}
```

I believe there is a better way to do that, probably in a few lines of code. I tried to figure out something with basic FP functions such as map or filter but I end up with nothing.

My question is: How to perform the operation coded above in elegant way(probably using more advanced fuctional programming)?

Comment: This may be better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I second that this question is best for codereview.stackexchange.com. That's the right place when you want help improving code that works. This is the place for when you want help with code that doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks guys, I already posted my code there, I didn't know about the existence of codereview here to be honest :) Should I delete this question here or flag it?

Comment: What is supposed to happen when you have two entries with the same `name` and `dose` and `time` as in your example?

Comment: Actually it does not matter, additional entries with the same time are redundant

Comment: It does matter. If they are redundant, do you want those eliminated, or do you want them appended to the dosage list? Come on, I can't provide an algorithm if you can't provide a clear spec.

Comment: Ok I understand. If the enteies are exactly the same I want them to be appended as well. Sorry for inconvenience:)

Answer (score 2):

So at first, you should restructure your objects little better, so it is easier and more readable, possibly like this:

```
struct Dosage {

    // Declare variables
    let dose : String
    let time : String

    // Get dosage from drug data
    init(drugData : DrugData) {
        self.dose = drugData["dose"]!
        self.time = drugData["time"]!
    }
}


class Drug {

    let name : String
    var dosage = [Dosage]()

    init(drugData : DrugData) {

        // Assign name
        self.name = drugData["dose"]!

        // Append dosage
        self.appendDosage(drugData)
    }


    func appendDosage(drugData : DrugData) {

        self.dosage.append(Dosage(drugData: drugData))
    }
}
```

Notice that I am using TypeAlias which masks definition of your dictionary, like this:

```
typealias DrugData = [String : String]
```

Define your storage for drugs:

```
var drugs = [String : Drug]()
```

Now when you have definitions all sorted out, you can improve your algorithm:

```
func createDrugs() {

    // Your drug definitions
    var array = [["drugName":"Amotaks", "time":"17.00", "dose":"5"]]

    // Iterate through them
    for drugDefinition in array {

        // Check if there is a name, if yes, get it
        if let name = drugDefinition["drugName"] {

            // If drug exists, just update it, otherwise create it
            if let drug = drugs[name] {
                drug.appendDosage(drugDefinition)
            } else {
                drugs[name] = Drug(drugData: drugDefinition)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I used dictionary that uses drug name as the key. Searching using key is extremely fast, much faster than iterating through entire array.I believe there is many more possibilities for improvement, but I think that is for you now :) Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

First, let's make it possible to see how we're doing by making your Drug class printable:

```
class Drug : CustomStringConvertible {

    var name:String
    var dosage:[(dose:String,time:String)]

    init(name:String){
        self.name = name
        self.dosage = []
    }

    var description:String {
        return "\(name):\(dosage)"
    }
}
```

Then here's my first attempt:

```
let array = [["drugName":"Amotaks", "time":"17.00", "dose":"5"], ["drugName":"Amotaks", "time":"18.00", "dose":"5"], ["drugName":"Amotaks", "time":"18.00", "dose":"5"], ["drugName":"Amotaks", "time":"17.00", "dose":"5"], ["drugName":"Claritin", "time":"17.00", "dose":"5"], ["drugName":"Claritin", "time":"18.00", "dose":"5"]]

var d = [String:Drug]()
for drug in array.map ({
    d -> Drug in
    let drug = Drug(name:d["drugName"]!)
    drug.dosage = [(dose:d["dose"]!, time:d["time"]!)]
    return drug
}) {
    let name = drug.name
    if d[name] == nil {
        d[name] = drug
    } else {
        d[name]!.dosage += drug.dosage
    }
}

let result = Array(d.values)
print(result) 
// [Claritin:[("5", "17.00"), ("5", "18.00")], Amotaks:[("5", "17.00"), ("5", "18.00"), ("5", "18.00"), ("5", "17.00")]]
```

Comment: While your code is definitely faster, for programmers on beginner level which author clearly is (no offense!), it is very hard to understand. It is always better to provide comments which explain what the stuff do.

Comment: @JiriTrecak Don't nag me. You've provided your own answer, it's good, it speaks for itself. As for me, the user asked for "more elegant" (whatever that means), I tried to provide something more elegant and more "Swifty". You and I actually arrived at very similar solutions at the same moment. Don't worry, be happy.

Comment: I am sorry (i mean it) that it sounded that way, it wasn't meant to be rude or anything. I am just saying that it is improbable that people will understand closures and the way how map function works by simply putting code here, which makes it problematic to learn and adjust the code for their usage. I deeply respect that you put time to this answer, it is definitely more "swifty" than mine. Here good sir, have a :beer: :)

Comment: @JiriTrecak The OP can always read my book: [anonymous functions] http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_anonymous_functions [map method] http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_array_enumeration_and_transformation The question wasn't "teach me Swift" - my book does that in any case. The question was "what's a more elegant way?" This is one, I think.